# track hash links like pages with google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to track hash links like pages with google analytics immediately(with in 2 hours)?

If there is no simple way of doing this, how can I add a track event to an onclick event with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is actually sent to [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) (check the note)

However it will not show up in your dashboard. To manually send a hash to Google Analytics you can bind a [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) event which will trigger a pageview as suggested for the query string in the bottom section.

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
   ga('send', 'pageview', location.hash);
}
```